# Bootstrap carousel slides out of order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Strange problem here, and I can't find anyone else who's encountered it.

My carousel runs fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (mac and pc) but in IE7 and 8, the slides appear completely out of order after the first slide appears on page load. The first slide is always correct. If I start using the previous/next buttons, they will cycle through in the correct order.

BUT, I've had 2 other people test in Chrome, FF and Safari, and they are sometimes out of order.

bootstrap-carousel.js is untouched from the original (freshly downloaded).

I do have some custom js going on for some other carousels on my site that use pagination. this one doesn't use it though. The custom code does not refer to the div id of the problem carousel. However when I remove the link on the page to the custom js, the problem goes away, so obviously it's related but I can't figure out why.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/home-slide-girl.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/home-slide-woman.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/home-slide-mom.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/home-slide-choco.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
      </div><!-- end myCarousel -->
```

here is the custom js that the other carousels use for pagination:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $('#myCarousel2, #myCarousel3').each(
        function() {
            var html = '<div class="carousel-nav " data-target="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"><ul>';

            for(var i = 0; i < $(this).find('.item').size(); i ++) {
                html += '<li><a';
                if(i == 0) {
                        html += ' class="active"';
                }

                var item = $(this).find('.item').get(i);

                html += ' href="#">&nbsp;'  + $(item).attr('data-title') + '</a></li>';
            }

            html += '</ul></li>';
            $(this).after(html);
            $('.carousel-control.left[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').hide();
        }
    ).bind('slid',
        function(e) {
            var nav = $('.carousel-nav[data-target="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"] ul');
            var index = $(this).find('.item.active').index();
            var item = nav.find('li').get(index);

            nav.find('li a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(item).find('a').addClass('active');

            if(index == 0) {
                $('.carousel-control.left[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.carousel-control.left[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').fadeIn();
            }

            if(index == nav.find('li').size() - 1) {
                $('.carousel-control.right[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').fadeOut();
            } else {
                $('.carousel-control.right[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    );

    $('.carousel-nav a').bind('click',
        function(e) {
            var index = $(this).parent().index();
            var carousel = $('#' + $(this).closest('.carousel-nav').attr('data-target'));

            carousel.carousel(index);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );

    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle'); // Start the animation automatically
}
```

);

Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: What do you mean 'out of sync' ? And it would be easier for you and for everybody if you could reproduce the bug with minimal code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for example.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say out of order. They don't go in the order they are coded in the UL. And, I will do that, thanks.

Comment: Even for 'out of order', you should look for a pattern, it certainly isn't random. About that, check that the `$('.carousel-nav a')` elements don't get binded several times for the sliding (by you, or by the default `.carousel-control` class).

Comment: It looks like the last line in the custom js is for some reason making it go out of order:    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle'); // Start the animation automatically  ... I am not sure why that line is in there, since the paginated carousels don't seem to depend on it. Removing it does the trick.

Comment: Thank you, @Sherbrow (see my last comment for what I discovered). Maybe this will help someone who has multiple carousels and is doing pagination but only on some of them.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it